# Can we use sonarQube to completely replace the custom-build security testing scenarios?

Tags: security, testing, sonarqube, bdd

I see that sonarQube  can be used for measuring code quality and for finding security vulnerabilities. I am having hard time deciding whether to replace the custom-build BDD security testing scenarios with sonarQube testing for my backend services. BDD testing usually takes longer than the sonarQube analysis. I would appreciate your suggestions on this.

Thanks

Comment: Off-hand I would say these two things are complementary, but could you provide some details of your BDD scenarios?

Comment: I do BDD testing using cucumber. One example test scenario is testing resource-access with valid/invalid credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two things are complementary. I wouldn't stop either in favor of the other.